# EasyPHP Windows7 wrong PATH variable

Tags: windows, path, php

I got the problem with env variable PATH in Windows 7. Unfortunately PHP-CLI see PATH variable incorrect. How to solve my problem?

Server info 
Apache/2.4.2 (Win32) PHP/5.4.6
PHP Version 5.4.6

Package: EASYPHP e.devserver 12.1
with PHP 5.4.6 (up to 5.4.11 / 5.5.0 alpha 3)

Regards, 
Mateusz

```
$ php
Failed loading c:\bin;.;C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\local\bin;C:\Program Files (x
86)\Git\mingw\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin;c:\Windows\system32;c:\Windows;
c:\Windows\System32\Wbem;c:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;c:\Program
Files\Dell\DW WLAN Card;c:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_30\bin;c:\ant\bin;c
:\EasyPHP\php\php546x130118150312\php\php546x130118150312\php_xdebug-2.2.1-5.4-v
c9.dll
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:\bin;.;C:\Program F
iles (x86)\Git\local\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\mingw\bin;C:\Program Files (
x86)\Git\bin;c:\Windows\system32;c:\Windows;c:\Windows\System32\Wbem;c:\Windows\
System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;c:\Program Files\Dell\DW WLAN Card;c:\Program F
iles (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_30\bin;c:\ant\bin;c:\EasyPHP\php\php546x130118150312\ph
p\php546x130118150312\ext\php_bz2.dll' - Nie mo┐na odnalečŠ okreťlonego modu│u.
 in Unknown on line 0
```

Comment: Its a problem with php ini directive `extension_dir` not with $PATH. PHP cannot find the bz2 and xdebug extensions

Comment: How can you say that the Path variable is incorrect? What *is* the problem you got? Does it have a name? What hinders you to troubleshoot your problem in concrete?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem. I have changed the `$PATH` with the complete path (in the php.ini) and have removed the `yaz` extension. Then it was working.